# undefined method `visit' for Selenium::WebDriver::Driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, rspec, webdriver, capybara

Trying to write a simple capybara example against google but getting

```
undefined method `visit' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x000000055f8cc8>
```

I  can use

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com/")
```

but I can't use

```
driver.visit("http://www.google.com/")
```

I have:

```
require "rspec"
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require "capybara"
require "capybara/rspec"
require "capybara/dsl"

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL
end

Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.run_server = false
  config.default_driver = :selenium
  config.app_host = 'https://www.google.com'
end

describe "Google Search", type: :feature do

  it "Tests Google" do
    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
    driver.visit "http://www.google.com/"   <-- Error
    fill_in('input', with: '123')
    find_element('input', "Google Search").click
    driver.quit
  end

end
```

Note that I have to use chrome as my selenium firefox setup is out of sync (common problem over time - it's unable to start firefox in 60 secs).  But chrome works and the browser comes up.

This simple ruby only example *does* work however so seems like some sort of rspec setup issue

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.get "http://google.com"

element = driver.find_element :name => "q"
element.send_keys "Cheese!"
element.submit

puts "Page title is #{driver.title}"

wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
wait.until { driver.title.downcase.start_with? "cheese!" }

puts "Page title is #{driver.title}"
driver.quit
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using the driver directly - you should be calling visit on the session (if you're managing your own sessions you would call it on whatever variable you used, if you're letting Capybara manage the sessions you should be calling it on page).

The reason Firefox isn't working for you is because Firefox 47 broke something with selenium - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2110 - it will be fixed in a 47.0.1 release soon, or you can revert to 46.  If you want to stick with chrome you should register a version of the driver using chrome in your spec/rails_helper and specify that

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome  # for most people this would normally be assigned to javascript_driver, but since you're using selenium for all tests we can just assign to default_driver
```

Then you would just do

```
describe "Google Search", type: :feature do

  it "Tests Google" do
    page.visit "http://www.google.com/"  #technically the page may not be required here but it can prevent method name collisions with other libraries
    page.fill_in('input', with: '123')  
    find_element('input', "Google Search").click  # I'm guessing this is your own defined method since Capybara doesn't have a find_element method? 
  end    
end
```